# Next-auth custom auth provider with custom backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-auth

auth authentication but i'm having an issue with sessions

My next-auth version is 4.0.0-beta.4(also tried beta.7 with same results)

I have my own JWT token backend that takes a username and password. And gives back an object with accesstoken, refreshtoken, expiretime and resfresh-time

So im trying to use that backend to handle session state with next-auth.
I manage to set the cookie "next-auth.session-token". But the session is always undefined when i'm trying to getSession.

And i don't have any sessions in my firefox browser.

```
const options = {
    providers: [
        Credentials({
            name: "Credentials",
            credentials: {
                username: {
                    label: "Username",
                    type: "text"
                },
                password: {
                    label: "Password",
                    type: "password"
                }
            },
            session: {
                jwt: true,
                maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 // the session will last 30 days
            },
            authorize: async (credentials) => {
                const tokenUrl = "http://192.168.0.8:8081/api/auth/token"
                const token = await fetch(tokenUrl, {
                    method: "POST",
                    mode: "cors",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        username: credentials.username,
                        password: credentials.password
                    })
                })
                    .then(res => res.json())
                console.log("token: ", token)
                if (token) {
                    const userUrl = "http://192.168.0.8:8081/admin/user/username/" + credentials.username;
                    const user = await fetch(userUrl, {
                        method: "GET",
                        mode: "cors",
                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type": "application/json",
                            "Authorization": "Bearer " + token.access_token
                        }
                    }).then(res => res.json())

                    return {
                        token,
                        user
                    };
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }),
    ],
    session: {
        jwt: true
    },
    pages: {
        signIn: "/login",
    },
    secret: "TEST",
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            // Initial call
            if (user) {
                return {
                    accessToken: user.token.access_token,
                    accessTokenExpires: Date.now() + user.token.expire_time * 1000,
                    refreshToken: user.token.refresh_token,
                    user: user.user,
                }
            }
            // Subsequent calls
            return token;
        },
        async session(session) {
            session.name = session.token.user.fullName
            session.accessToken = session.token.accessToken
            session.refreshToken = session.token.refreshToken
            return session;
        }
    }
}
```

Here i'm trying to get the session after logging in

```
export default function Home() {

  const { data: session } = getSession();

  console.log("session: ", session)

  return (


    < div >
    </div >
  )
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What ever happened with this?  I'm about to start on the same type of thing and would rather not reinvent the wheel if it's out there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was using the wrong method. I needed to use the useSession method instead of getSession. Then it worked.

Comment: Please explain your answer in detail. It may help someone in future!

Comment: If you could please have a full example of your working code it would be great. Also, what did you do to include the token you got from your back-end in every API request you make after you sign in successfully?